# How to make a dynamic path in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, path

Every time i transfer my vb.net files together with a report in other PC. I always have to change the directory of the report so that it will work on other computer.

Example

From(PC1)

```
Report.Load("C:\Users\SFAC\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SASApp\SASApp\RegistrarsBack.rpt")
```

to this directory(PC2)

```
Report.Load("C:\Users\SAS\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SASApp\SASApp\RegistrarsBack.rpt")
```

Here is the error that i encounter when transferring my files to PC2 during runtime.

[image]

Is there a smart way to deal with this? Thanks

Comment: yes, when loading the project together with a report ( crystal report files to other PC). I always have to change the directory of the report so that it will work on other computer. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I've now deleted two different answers to this question, because you can't seem to make up your mind what it is you're asking. So I'm voting to close it as unclear until you edit it to state **clearly and specifically** what it is you're wanting to ask. Are you asking about **transferring your project and it's files** to different machines so you can work on code on either of them? Or are you asking about finding the current directory your application is running from **at runtime**? I've answered both ways, and you've not been satisfied with either of them.

Comment: @ken White, If u think i do not explain it clearly, i apologize. Do not expect too much to a person that is hard to speak english and trying to explain the best way they can. I think you are a perfect person that you are happy offending person and make them feel that they are stupid.

Comment: The way this site works is that there are two halves. Your half is first, where you *clearly and specifically* explain the problem you're trying to solve, and ask a *specific question* related to that problem. We can then do our half of the job, which is answering that question. The second half can not be completed until the first part has been done. It's your job to complete that first half, so we don't waste our time doing our half only to find it's not really what you meant. I've done my part of the job two times now for absolutely no reason. So you need to properly do your part now.

Comment: I'm also not the first to raise this issue; see the answer you *have* received, where the person answering also says your question is unclear. You've done nothing to make it more clear. That's not **our** fault.

Comment: Your answer is good and that's give me an idea on how to deal with this. My comment is just a followup question. I do not know that they are in different approach with `transferring your project and it's files` and this `finding the current directory your application is running from at runtime`

Comment: So your question is in fact about copying code between the two machines? If so, edit to say so and I can put my last answer back, and all is well. If it's not, then edit to explain that you're asking about your running program, I'll leave my answer deleted, and again all is well. You're leaving it unclear, and that's not going to leave things all well. :-) If you actually have *two questions* (one about copying code and one about getting the folder at runtime), then make this one clear about one of them and create a new post to ask about the other.

Comment: i think this is what i am looking for `about finding the current directory your application is running from at runtime` Can you show me the difference of the two?I'm sorry i hope you understand that i am new to programming and hard to speak in english. I really apologize.  thanks

Comment: No, I can't answer both questions here at the same time. This is a Question and Answer site, not *QuestionS* and *AnswerS*. If you have two separate questions, create two separate posts. I understand that English is not everyone's first language, and what you've written is good. It's just not clear which question you're asking here.

Comment: OK.. Please leave your answer back. And i will just post a different question for the running from at runtime. I hope you can visit it also :-)

Comment: @KenWhite i will post a screenshot to make it clearer about my error during run time.

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode paths. You should always use dynamic paths like the application folder or the AppData folder. What I'm about to show you is half-hardcoded, but you really should make it fully dynamic: `Report.Load(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SASApp\SASApp\RegistrarsBack.rpt"))`

Comment: @VisualVincent thanks for the comment. i think that your way of creating a path is what i am looking for, i will try this later and give feedback.

Comment: @VisualVincent When trying your code, I got 3 errors. 1 `Path is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level` 2.  `My is not a member of system.Environment.Specialfolder ` 3. `Comma,')' or a valid expression continuation expected. `

Comment: Import System.IO, should be the first suggested fix for error 1. The other ones I don't know, could be a cause of the missing import, or you've written it wrong or something went wrong while copying. See if that still happens after you've imported System.IO.

Answer (score 0):

The content of your post doesn't necessarily seem to match the title but, if the question is how to get the current working directory, then the answer is to use `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.  That will generally return the path from which the current EXE was run.  That said, that may not be the initial working directory and the working directory may change over the course of a session.

I should also mention that, if you just use a file name without a folder path, it will be interpreted as being in the current working directory.  I would recommend doing it explicitly rather than implicitly though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to copy your .rpt file inside **bin\Debug\Report** folder of the project.

Than to reach that location dynamically, you need to write down following code.

```
Dim path As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Report\ReportName.rpt"
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = path
```